# How can i delete has many relation in grails with out belongto

Tags: java, grails

I have following scenario

```
class User{

String name
static constraints = {
details  nullable: true
}
 static hasMany = [details: Details]
}

class Details{
String applicationID
static constraints = {
images  nullable: true
}
static belongsTo = [user: User]
 static hasMany = [images: Images]
}
class Images{
String applicationImage
}
```

I have a user which have many Details and Details have many Images.when i am trying to delete user get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException. how can i delete user.

```
def deleteUser()
User user=User.get(params.id)
if(user.details) {
                Details details = Details.get(user.details.id)

                if(user.details.images) {
                    def detls= Details.findAllByDetails(details)
                    detls.each {
                        def image = it.images
                        if(image) {
                            Details detailsInstance = Details.get(it.id)
                            image.each { im ->
                                Image image1 = Image.get(im.id);
                                println(image1)
                                detailsInstance.removeFromImages(image1)
                                image1.delete(flush: true)
                            }
                            detailsInstance.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
                        }
                    }
                }
user.delete(flush:true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, first off, the code from your controller does not really match to the code of your domain classes (e.g. names of the domain classes are not matching). That is probably why I cannot reproduce the ConcurrentModificationException.

It depends on what excactly you want to do when deleting a user. If you just want to delete the user and his details but not the images it is sufficient to do a

```
def delete() {
    User user = User.get(params.id)
    user.delete(flush: true)
}
```

If you also want to delete his images you could add a

```
static belongsTo = [detail: Detail]
```

to the Image class. In this case the images will be deleted by cascading (see http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/ for a better understanding)

If you want to keep the images in some cases you can do it like this:

```
User user = User.get(params.id)

def images  = []

if (user) {
    user.details.each { detail ->
        detail.images.each { image ->
            images.add(image)
        }
    }

    user.delete(flush: true)
    images*.delete(flush: true)
}
```

Comment: @Bhushan: Have you been able to solve this issue with my answer?